# Laravel: Search Results paginated, next page does not display next page results for searched keyword

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have this index function that gets all the products from the database in my `ProductsController` which uses this route:

```
    Route::get('{store}/products', [
        'as'    => 'store.products.show',
        'uses'  => 'ProductsController@index',
    ]);
```

```
    public function index(Request $request, $store)
    {
        $store      = Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
        $products   = Product::where('store_id', $store->uuid)
                        ->orderBy('display_order', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->paginate();
        $search = null;

        return view('platform-management.products.index', compact(
            'store',
            'products',
            'search'
        ));
    }
```

When I click the next page in the pagination, the URL changes to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/platform-management/store1/products?page=2`
and displays the next page properly.
[image]
 My problem now is that, I used the same logic to my `search_result` function:

```
    public function search_results(Request $request, $store)
    {
        $store      = Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
        $substr     = $request->search;

        $products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$substr}%");


        $products   = $products->where('store_id', $store->uuid)
                        ->orderBy('name')
                        ->paginate();

        return view('platform-management.products.search', compact(
            'store',
            'substr',
            'products'
        ));
    }
```

which uses the route:

```
    Route::get('{store}/products/search', [
        'as'    => 'products.search',
        'uses'  => 'ProductsController@search_results',
    ]);
```

It does the job and it works. when I try to search a word, for example:
[image]

It does search for the products with the word "marikit" in it.
please take a look at the URL,

and now if I click the next page of the search results,

[image]

the word I am searching for "marikit" is not included in the url anymore. and the search results displaying are the same as what the products' second page is showing.
I tried to change the url to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/platform-management/store1/products/search?search=marikit?page=2` but it just appended to the word being searched.

[image]

what did I miss? Thank you for the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters are started with a `?` and separated by a `&`. So your url should be.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/platform-management/store1/products/search?search=marikit&page=2
```